# Retrofit & RxJava multiple requests complete

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I need to do:

1. Request 2 lists of news from different websites
2. Combine results from requests
3. Sort items by date
4. Get 10 newest news
5. Save them
6. Show complete message

For example, I have this two observables:

```
Observable<RegionalNews> regionalNews;
Observable<NationalNews> nationalNews;

public interface NewsNationalService {
  @GET("news/national")
  Observable<News> getNationalNews();
}

public interface NewsRegionalService {
  @GET("news/regional")
  Observable<News> getRegionalNews();
}
```

Comment: Just create a combine function that is not combining anything and just showing your alert?

Comment: If you are just waiting for the responses from the APIs why don't you call the second API in the first API's onNext() callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to do something specific with the combined results, then merge() is enough:

```
Observable<RegionalNews> regionalNews = ...;
Observable<NationalNews> nationalNews = ...;

Observable
.merge(regionalNews, nationalNews)
.ignoreElements()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnComplete(() -> { /* show alert */ })
.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `zip` operator to call 2 requests async and save or process their data on response.

For example.

Below are two `Observable`

```
Observable<ResponseOne> responseOneObservable = getRetrofitClient().getDataOne()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable<ResponseTwo> responseTwoObservable = getRetrofitClient().getDataTwo()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Using `zip` operator on above two `Observable` as below.

```
Observable<ArrayList<TestData>> testDataObservable = Observable.zip(responseOneObservable, responseTwoObservable, new Func2<ResponseOne, ResponseTwo, ArrayList<TestData>>() {
            @Override
                public ArrayList<TestData> call(ResponseOne responseOne, ResponseTwo responseTwo) {
                  ArrayList<TestData> testDataList = new ArrayList();
                      // process data from response responseOne & responseTwo
                  return testDataList;
            } 
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<TestData>>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(ArrayList<TestData> testDataList) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted" ); 
            // you can show alert here or do something when completed 
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError Throwable: " + t.toString() );
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have 4 APIs to combine in `zip` each APIs returns list of objects in a string of each 4 tables from the server. I want to parse each JSON list to specific `ActiveAndroid` ORM class object using `gson` library and save it to SQLite. How can I differentiate each String response in `subscribe` method and parse it according to the object?

Comment: what is TestData  i want to use the responseOne and responseTwo on complete  but the zip returning ArrayList<TestData>

Comment: `TestData` is an custom class object. You can use any object instead of that as per your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Well it depends, as always. Do you need to process the returned values down the chain, or just save it?

In this implementation I use Single and Completable. You subscribe to the completable and you will get notified when both Singles finished.

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
        TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        Single<Long> request1 = Single.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, testScheduler)
                .doOnSuccess(aLong -> {
                    System.out.println("save to db.");
                });
        Single<Long> request2 = Single.timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, testScheduler)
                .doOnSuccess(aLong -> {
                    System.out.println("save to db.");
                });

        Completable completable = Single.zip(request1, request2, (aLong, aLong2) -> aLong).toCompletable();

        TestObserver<Void> test = completable.test();

        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1010, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        test.assertComplete();
}
```

You also can use flatMapCompletable instead of doOnSuccess

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    Completable request1 = Single.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, testScheduler)
            .flatMapCompletable(this::saveToDb);

    Completable request2 = Single.timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, testScheduler)
            .flatMapCompletable(this::saveToDb);

    // need to cheat here, becuase completeable does not provide zip
    Completable completable = Single.zip(request1.toSingle(() -> 1), request1.toSingle(() -> 1), (aLong, aLong2) -> aLong)
            .toCompletable();

    TestObserver<Void> test = completable.test();

    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1010, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    test.assertComplete();
}

private Completable saveToDb(long value) {
    return Completable.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`zip` is the way to combine `observables`. Combining their results is just a consequence.

If you want to wait for both observables to finish (complete), the easiest way is to use `zip`. You just don't have to use the results of your requests in the combining function. Just use this function as a way to emit something different when both of those calls finish. When this function emits an item:

> [...] do something when all requests completed (show alert for example)

For example like this (executing `someOtherCall` when both of those requests finish):

```
Observable<Integer> obs1 = ...;
Observable<Long> obs2 = ...;

Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, new Func2<Integer, Long, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Integer integer, Long aLong) {
        return "something completely different";
    }
}).flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Float>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Float> call(String s) {
        return performSomeOtherCall();
    }
}).subscribe(...);
```