# JSON Array With Volley Showing Only One data

Tags: android-volley

I am trying to display array data using JSON Volley in `PostsBasedOnCategory.java`. Array data that I want to display are, Title post, and excerpt based on specific category from https://www.kisahmuslim.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories. But unfortunately, it only showing one result.

Below you can check my code

**DaftarCategories.java**

```
public class CallingPage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        HttpURLConnection conn;
        java.net.URL url = null;
        private int page = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            showNoFav(false);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                url = new URL("https://www.kisahmuslim.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories");

            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {
                    return("koneksi gagal");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }

        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            JsonArrayRequest stringRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, SumberPosts.HOST_URL+"wp/v2/categories/", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // display response
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Size: "+response.length());

                    // agar setiap kali direfresh data tidak redundant
                    typeForPosts.clear();

                    for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++) { //ambil semua objek yang ada
                        final CategoriesModel post = new CategoriesModel();
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Object at " + i + response.get(i));
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            post.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
                            post.setPostURL(obj.getString("link"));

                            //Get category name
                            post.setCategory(obj.getString("name"));

                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            // getting article konten
                            JSONObject postCategoryParent = obj.getJSONObject("_links");
                            JSONArray postCategoryObj = postCategoryParent.getJSONArray("wp:post_type");
                            JSONObject postCategoryIndex = postCategoryObj.getJSONObject(0); //ambil satu objek saja
                            String postCategoryUrl = postCategoryIndex.getString("href"); //satu objek yang dimaksud adalah href

                            if(postCategoryUrl != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, postCategoryIndex.getString("href"));

                                JsonArrayRequest getKonten = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, postCategoryUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONArray respon) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, respon.toString() + "Size: "+respon.length());
                                        for(int d=0; d<respon.length(); d++) {
                                            try {
                                                //Log.d(TAG, "Object at " + i + respon.get());
                                                JSONObject objek = respon.getJSONObject(d); //ambil semua artikel yang tersedia di postCategoryUrl

                                                post.setId(objek.getInt("id"));
                                                post.setCreatedAt(objek.getString("date"));
                                                post.setPostURL(objek.getString("link"));

                                                //Get category title
                                                JSONObject titleObj = objek.getJSONObject("title");
                                                post.setJudul(titleObj.getString("rendered"));

                                                //Get excerpt
                                                JSONObject exerptObj = objek.getJSONObject("excerpt");
                                                post.setExcerpt(exerptObj.getString("rendered"));

                                                // Get content
                                                JSONObject contentObj = objek.getJSONObject("content");
                                                post.setContent(contentObj.getString("rendered"));

                                            }
                                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }// for category

                                    } //onResponse2

                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //getKonten
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                    }

                                });

                                queue.add(getKonten);
                            } //if postCategoryUrl
                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                            typeForPosts.add(post);

                        } //try 1
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } //for 1

                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recycleViewWordPress.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } //onResponse1

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //stringRequest
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    showNoFav(true);
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Tidak bisa menampilkan data. Periksa kembali sambungan internet Anda", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);

        } //onPostExecute
    } //CallingPage

    @Override
    public void onPostingSelected(int pos) {
        CategoriesModel click = typeForPosts.get(pos);

        excerpt = click.getExcerpt();
        //gambar = click.getPostImg();
        judul = click.getJudul();
        //url = click.getPostURL();
        content = click.getContent();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("judul", judul);
        //bundle.putString("gambar", gambar);
        //bundle.putString("url", url);
        bundle.putString("content", content);
        bundle.putString("excerpt", excerpt);

        PostsBasedOnCategory bookFragment = new PostsBasedOnCategory();
        bookFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getContext();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContainerFragment, bookFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
```

**PostsBasedOnCategory.java**

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_wordpress, container,false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        swipeRefreshLayout =(SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        recycleViewWordPress =(RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycleViewWordPress);
        pb = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel);
        noFavtsTV = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.no_favt_text);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recycleViewWordPress.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        });

        typeForPosts = new ArrayList<CategoriesModel>();
        recycleViewWordPress.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycleViewWordPress.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recycleViewWordPress.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mAdapter = new AdapterCategoryPosts(getContext(), typeForPosts, this);
        recycleViewWordPress.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        loadData();

    }

    public void loadData() {
        Bundle bundel = this.getArguments();
        long id = bundel.getLong("id");
        String kategori = bundel.getString("kategori");
        String title = bundel.getString("judul");
        String excerpt = bundel.getString("excerpt");
        String pict = bundel.getString("gambar");
        String url = bundel.getString("url");
        String konten = bundel.getString("konten");

        CategoriesModel list = new CategoriesModel();

        list.setId(id);
        list.setCategory(kategori);
        list.setJudul(title);
        list.setExcerpt(excerpt);
        list.setPostImg(pict);
        list.setPostURL(url);
        list.setContent(konten);

        typeForPosts.add(list);
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
2019-09-07 12:01:27.941 11246-11246/com.kursusarabic.arabicforfun D/postFrag: [{"id":12,"count":53,"description":"","link":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/category\/kisah-nyata\/biografi-ulama","name":"Biografi Ulama","slug":"biografi-ulama","taxonomy":"category","parent":29,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/12"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"up":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/29"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=12"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}},{"id":26,"count":8,"description":"","link":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/category\/download","name":"Download","slug":"download","taxonomy":"category","parent":0,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/26"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=26"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}},{"id":1812,"count":9,"description":"","link":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/category\/info","name":"Info","slug":"info","taxonomy":"category","parent":0,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/1812"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=1812"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}},{"id":17,"count":3,"description":"","link":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/category\/kisah-nyata\/kisah-birrul-walidain","name":"Kisah Birrul Walidain","slug":"kisah-birrul-walidain","taxonomy":"category","parent":29,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/17"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"up":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/29"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=17"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}},{"id":25,"count":31,"description":"","link":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/category\/kisah-nyata\/kisah-hidayah-islam","name":"Kisah Hidayah Islam","slug":"kisah-hidayah-islam","taxonomy":"category","parent":29,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/25"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"up":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/29"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=25"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}},{"id":16,"count":49,"description":"","link":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/category\/kisah-nyata\/kisah-kaum-durhaka","name":"Kisah Kaum Durhaka","slug":"kisah-kaum-durhaka","taxonomy":"category","parent":29,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/16"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"up":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/29"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=1
2019-09-07 12:01:27.942 11246-11246/com.kursusarabic.arabicforfun D/postFrag: Object at 0{"id":12,"count":53,"description":"","link":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/category\/kisah-nyata\/biografi-ulama","name":"Biografi Ulama","slug":"biografi-ulama","taxonomy":"category","parent":29,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/12"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"up":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/29"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/kisahmuslim.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=12"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}}
2019-09-07 12:01:27.942 11246-11246/com.kursusarabic.arabicforfun D/postFrag: https://kisahmuslim.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=12
```

Comment: What does `response` have in it ,also what does this -> `Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Size: "+response.length());` prints ?

Comment: I've updated the code. Please check it!

Comment: The response is: It can load category post perfectly. When one of those category clicked, it should display all posts based on that category, but it only display one post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call network requests in loop, Use async processing or

[Retrofit & RxJava multiple requests complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468043/retrofit-rxjava-multiple-requests-complete)

and after updating `typeForPosts`, there is no need to setAdapter on recyclerview just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thanks for your clue mate. I'll try it. Can you fix me another problem? Actually, maybe is so simple... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832747/display-list-of-data-based-on-name-and-image-object