# Display List Of Data Based On Name and Image Object

Tags: android-volley

I wanna display list of data based on name and image object with JSON volley. But can't display in accordance with expectations. For example: The expectation is, if I click Tea, it will show: Green tea, Sweet Tea, etc. If I click Coffee, it will show a list of coffee: Black coffee, white coffee, etc

Below you can my code:

**MainActivity**

```
/**
         * fetches json by making http calls
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    List<HomeModel> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<HomeModel>>() {}.getType());

                    // adding contacts to contacts list
                    homeModelList.clear();

                    for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++) {
                        try{
                            Log.d(TAG, "Object at " + i + response.get(i));
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject mulai = obj.getJSONObject("begin");
                            JSONArray ambilDoa = mulai.getJSONArray("self"); //ambil semua doa yang diapit dengan {}

                            for(int x=0; x<ambilDoa.length(); x++) {
                                JSONObject listDoa = ambilDoa.getJSONObject(x); // paparkan semua doa yang telah diambil tadi

                                //ambil elemen berdasarkan spesifikasi doa
                                nama = listDoa.getString("name");
                                gambar = listDoa.getString("image");
                                imagedd = listDoa.getString("imagedd");

                                HomeModel hM = new HomeModel();
                                hM.setName(nama);
                                hM.setImage(imagedd);
                                homeModelList.add(hM);

                                JSONArray arrDonga = listDoa.getJSONArray("mName");
                                JSONArray arrLatinDoa = listDoa.getJSONArray("latinDoa");
                                JSONArray arrArtiDoa = listDoa.getJSONArray("artiDoa");
                                JSONArray arrSumberDoa = listDoa.getJSONArray("sumberDoa");
                                JSONArray arrBaca = listDoa.getJSONArray("bName");

                                String[] doa = new String[arrDonga.length()];
                                String[] latin = new String[arrLatinDoa.length()];
                                String[] arti = new String[arrArtiDoa.length()];
                                String[] sumber = new String[arrSumberDoa.length()];
                                String[] baca = new String[arrBaca.length()];

                                for(int y=0; y<arrDonga.length(); y++) {
                                    doa[y] = arrDonga.getString(y);
                                    latin[y] = arrLatinDoa.getString(y);
                                    arti[y] = arrArtiDoa.getString(y);
                                    sumber[y] = arrSumberDoa.getString(y);
                                    baca[y] = arrBaca.getString(y);

                                    DetailModelDoa mD = new DetailModelDoa(doa[y], latin[y], arti[y], sumber[y], baca[y], imagedd, DetailModelDoa.BACA_DOA);
                                    nameValuePairs.add(mD);
                                }

                                Bundle extra = new Bundle();
                                extra.putSerializable("objects", nameValuePairs);

                                /* Move on to step 2 */
                                su = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailDoa.class);
                                su.putExtra("extra", extra);
                            }

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // refreshing recycler view
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // error in getting json
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak bisa menampilkan data. Periksa kembali sambungan internet Anda", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Data Tidak bisa ditampilkan. Periksa kembali sambungan internet Anda");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    showNoFav(true);
                }
            });

            HomeSearch.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

        } //onpostexecute

    } //AsyncLogin


    @Override
    public void onContactSelected(int pos) {
        HomeModel click = homeModelList.get(pos);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected: " + click.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        startActivity(su);

    }
```

**JSON Data**

```
[ 
   { 
     "begin": {

       "self": [

              {
                  "name": "Doa Bangun Tidur",
                  "image": "https://www.kafeinkode.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/banguntidur.jpeg",

                  "imagedd": "https://www.kafeinkode.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/banguntidur.jpeg", 

                  "mName": [ 
                   " الحَمْـدُ لِلّهِ الّذي أَحْـيانا بَعْـدَ ما أَماتَـنا وَإليه النُّـشور",
        "الحمدُ للهِ الذي عافاني في جَسَدي وَرَدّ عَليّ روحي وَأَذِنَ لي بِذِكْرِه",
        "لَا إِلَهَ إِلَّا اللهُ وَحْدَهُ لَا شَـرِيْكَ لَهُ. لَهُ الْمُلْكُ وَلَهُ الْحَمْدُ وَهُوَ عَلَى كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيْرٌ. سُبْحَانَ اللهِ وَالْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ وَلَا إِلَهَ إِلَّا اللهُ وَاللهُ أَكْبَرُ، وَلَا حَوْلَ وَلَا قُوَّةَ إِلَّا بِاللهِ الْعَلِيِّ الْعَظِيْمِ رَبِّ اغْفِرْ ليِ"
                 ],

                  "latinDoa": [ 
                       "Alhamdulillahilladzi ahyana ba'da ma amatana wa ilaihin nusyur",
        "Alhamdulillahilladzi 'afini fi jasadi wa rodda alayya ruhi wa adzina li bidzikrihi",
        "La ilaha illalllahu wahdahu la syarika lah, lahul mulku wa lahul hamdu wa huwa ala kulli syain qodir, subhanallahi wal hamdulillah wa la ilaha illallahu wallahu akbar, wa la haula wa la quwwata illa billahil aliyyil adzim, rabbighfirli"
                    ],

                  "artiDoa": [
                      "Artinya:\nSegala puji bagi Allah Yang membangunkan kami setelah ditidurkan-Nya dan kepada-Nya kami dibangkitkan.",
        "Artinya:\nSegala puji bagi Allah Yang telah memberikan kesehatan kepada-ku, mengembalikan ruh, dan merestuiku untuk berdzikir kepada-Nya",
        "Tiada Tuhan selain Allah, Yang Maha Esa, tiada sekutu bagi-Nya. Bagi-Nya kerajaan dan pujian. Dia-lah Yang Maha Kuasa atas segala sesuatu. Maha suci Allah, segala puji bagi Allah, tiada Tuhan selain Allah, Allah Maha Besar, tiada daya dan kekuatan kecuali dengan pertolongan Allah Yang Maha Tinggi dan Maha Agung. Ya Tuhanku, ampunilah dosaku."
                   ],

                  "sumberDoa": [ 
                       "Sumber:\nHR. Bukhari dalam Fathul Bari 11/113 No. 6314 dan HR. Muslim 4/2083 No. 2711.",
        "Sumber:\nHR. Tirmidzi 5/473 No. 3401. Lihat Shahih Sunan Tirmidzi 3/144.",
        "Sumber:\nHR. Bukhari dalam Fathul Bari 3/39 No. 1154 dan selainnya. Lafazh menurut Ibnu Majah. Lihat Shahih Ibnu Majah 2/335."
                     ],

                  "bName": [
                             "Baca 1x",
                             "Baca 1x",
                             "Baca 1x"
                 ]

             },

             {
                 "name": "Doa Berhubungan Intim",
                 "image": "https://www.kafeinkode.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/jimak.jpeg",
                 "imagedd": "https://www.kafeinkode.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/jimak.jpeg", 

                 "doa": [ 
                    "بِسْمِ اللهِ اَللَّهُمَّ جَنِّبْنَا الشَّيْطَانَ وَجَنِّبِ الشَّيْطَانَ مَا رَزَقْتَنَا "
                        ],

                 "latinDoa": [ 
                       "Bismillahi Allahumma Jannibna assyaithana wa jannibi assyaithana ma razaqtana"
                       ],

                 "artiDoa": [
                      "Artinya:\nDengan Nama Allah, Ya Allah, Jauhkan kami dari setan, dan jauhkan setan untuk mengganggu apa yang Engkau rezekikan kepada kami."
                      ],

                 "sumberDoa": [ 
                        "Sumber:\nHR. Bukhari 6/141 No. 141 dan HR. Muslim 2/1028 No. 1434."
                        ],

                 "bName": [
                    "Baca 1x"
                 ]
             }

       ]

    }

  }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways you can implement here, like-

You can compare names in list of objects using `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` and place separately these matched objects and then display list according to those names.

Another one is Make `HashMap` whenerver you got response in JsonArray. For instance `HashMap<String,ArrayList<HomeModel>>` where you have to put `String` key as names like tea or cofee and `ArrayList` as a List of those objects whose names contains tea of coffee. So when you click on coffee, you can get List of objects by only key value like that-

```
ArrayList<HomeModel> models = hashmap.get("coffee");
```

Comment: I dodn't know your keywords for classification, Just take an example of hashmap, You need to it yourself;